# multiple refs for inputs, works only last one

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to make a editable table using ref.

In this case I can only get last input's value through ref, but created multiple refs for it.

Why is it any ideas?

Please let me know if you need more info about it.

```js
import React, { useRef } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

import "./styles.css";

const Table = props => {
  const materials = Array(7).fill({
    a: "a",
    b: "b",
    aref: useRef(null),
    bref: useRef(null)
  });
  const handle = (index, key, ref) => {
    console.log(index, ref.current.value);
  };
  return (
    <>
      <table>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>a</th>
            <th>b</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          {materials.map((item, index) => {
            return (
              <tr key={index}>
                <td>
                  <input
                    onChange={e => handle(index, "a", item.aref)}
                    type="text"
                    ref={item.aref}
                  />
                </td>
                <td>
                  <input
                    onChange={e => handle(index, "b", item.bref)}
                    type="text"
                    ref={item.bref}
                  />
                </td>
              </tr>
            );
          })}
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </>
  );
};

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Table />
    </div>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/upbeat-breeze-sm7c6

Comment: How did you debug your code? What is it supposed to do? It's not clear enough what the issue is

Comment: @GalAbra I debug it through console and ref only works for last element in array

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Array.fill(value[, start[, end]])` will fill the array with `value` between `start` and `end`. So, your ref is same objects in your array. Try to change your code like this:

```
  // ...
  const materials = Array(7).fill(null).map(() => ({
    a: "a",
    b: "b",
    aref: useRef(null),
    bref: useRef(null)
  }))
  // ...
```

Comment: Do you know how to avoid warning "React Hook "useRef" cannot be called inside a callback. "?

Comment: ```const inputRefs = useRef<React.RefObject<HTMLInputElement>[]>(
  Array(8)
   .fill({})
   .map(() => createRef<HTMLInputElement>())
 );```

Answer (score 2):

I did a slight modification, which should work as your expectation.

```
const Table = props => {
  const materials = Array(7);

  for (var i=0;i<materials.length;i++){
    materials[i] = {
      a: "a",
      b: "b",
      aref: React.createRef(),
      bref: React.createRef()
    };
  }

  const handle = (index, key, ref) => {
    console.log(index, ref.current.value);
  };
  return (
    <>
      <table>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>a</th>
            <th>b</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          {materials.map((item, index) => {
            return (
              <tr key={index}>
                <td>
                  <input
                    onChange={e => handle(index, "a", item.aref)}
                    type="text"
                    ref={item.aref}
                  />
                </td>
                <td>
                  <input
                    onChange={e => handle(index, "b", item.bref)}
                    type="text"
                    ref={item.bref}
                  />
                </td>
              </tr>
            );
          })}
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </>
  );
};
```

Comment: Hi JillAndMe,to avoid warning in @acrazing 's answer, you should use "React.createRef()" instead of "useRef(null)" .  Sorry my reputation is below 50 that cannot add a comment in different posts yet.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is, you are iterating over `materials` array and creating your input's. In those created input's you are adding `ref`.

**As there is multiple elements with same `ref`, react might get confuse which one to pick and in a result it is picking up last one to get the values. So this indicates that react need `unique` `ref` to be used.**

That is why you are getting value for last input but not for others.

---

As per [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html),

> There are a few good use cases for refs:
>
> 1. Managing focus, text selection, or media playback.
> 2. Triggering imperative animations.
> 3. Integrating with third-party DOM libraries.

**Avoid using refs for anything that can be done declaratively.**

---

So when you have `onChange` for every input, I think no need to use ref to get value of input. You can directly get the values using `e.target.value`,

```
<input onChange={e => handle(index, "a", e)} type="text" />
```

```
const handle = (index, key, e) => {
    console.log(index, e.target.value);
};
```

[Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/thirsty-paper-b7reh?fontsize=14)

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue once, after a while i've realized that i was creating the refs inside a static `defaultProps`, therefore all the references were the same for all elements, and the same bug would appear